# Advantages/disavantages of including the comma operator?

Tags: language-design, operators, c

In many C style languages the `,` binary operator takes 2 expressions and simply returns the second one:

```
let a = 12, 42;
console.log(a);
// Output 42
```

This is quite useful, but many new languages don't have it. So I'm wondering if there is something wrong with it why my language shouldn't have it.

Comment: That's invalid JS btw, you would need `(12, 42)` because otherwise you're trying to declare a variable named `42`.

Comment: The main disadvantage of the comma operator in C is that it is easily confused with the use of commas to separate arguments in a function call.

Answer (score 14):

The benefit of the comma operator is that it allows you to include a sub-expression for its side-effects only. In languages without a comma operator, there are often ways around this ─ suppose `f` is an expression you want to evaluate just for its side-effects, and then `g` is the expression whose value you actually want:

- In languages with list or tuple literals, you can write `[f, g][1]`.
- In languages with dynamically-typed logical operators, you can write `(f || true) && g`.
- In languages with `let`-`in` expressions, you can write `let _ = f in g`.
- In most cases, you can define a function like `comma(f, g)` which just returns `g`.

So the comma operator does not really add expressiveness to the language, it just allows you to write this kind of expression explicitly instead of using an idiom. On the other hand, this kind of expression is rarely needed in real code written by humans; personally, I only use JavaScript's comma operator in Code Golf challenges or to simulate `let`-`in` expressions like `(x=f, g)` when compiling to JavaScript.

Also, including the comma operator like this may mean less syntax space is available for other things. For example, in Python, `(f, g)` or `f, g` are expressions which create a tuple, so they can't also mean something else.

The comma operator would also be almost entirely superfluous in languages where expressions cannot have side-effects, such as pure functional languages ─ the first operand would only matter if it was eagerly evaluated but diverged. (Haskell's `seq` behaves like this, and is [considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687392/12299000) by some.)

Comment: It's not *entirely* superfluous in non-strict pure functional languages if it behaves like [seq](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq). It would still be a strange design choice, though.

Comment: Regarding using a function `comma(f,g)`, or more precisely, function argument evaluation, in some languages the order of evaluation is not specified, but the comma operator evaluates left to right.

Comment: It tends to be used in C when you have places that only allow one expression, like the parts of a for-loop header. It's also frequently used in JS with `reduce()` along with short-form arrow functions, so you don't have to write a multi-statement function body.

Answer (score 10):

## Readability

The main problem programmers have with the comma operator is this would permit having multiple expressions in a single line, which is generally frowned upon.

```
x = 10;
y = 20;
z = 30;
if (a) {
    b();
}
```

Vs:

```
if (x = 10, y = 20, z = 30, a) {
    b();
}
```

## Better alternatives

If a language would add the ability to perform expressions *'inline'* in other expressions with the comma operator, they could just have [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) which perform the same task but are more powerful, as they can include statements instead of just expressions. Example:

```
int x = ({
    int y = 8;
    if (z) {
        f();
        y += 10;
    }
    y;
});
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that your "Better alternative" is more readable than the version with the comma operator?

Comment: @Barmar Not really. I am saying that it's more capable, which is objectively the case, because GCC-style blocks can handle statements such as `for` and variable declarations but comma operators can only handle expressions.

Answer (score 8):

The comma operator is easy to confuse with the syntax for generating lists. Even in the example you gave, one could easily think that `a` is a sequence of some sort containing 12 and 42, rather than just 42.

In fact, in Python (and probably some other languages), `a = 12, 42` does exactly that.

Comment: It's also easily confused with the syntax for separating arguments, so you need double parentheses: `func((a=12, 42))`

Answer (score 6):

In C and similar languages, `,` is used to separate expressions, while `;` is used to separate statements. In these languages, expressions and statements are different things, so it makes sense to have different separators for them.

In many new languages, e.g. Rust, almost everything is an expression. So you can use a single separator (usually `;`) to separate everything. `12, 42` in C is equivalent to `{ 12; 42 }` in Rust.

Comment: This is usually referred to as ISWIM or ML syntax as they were the first languages to use it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to have operators that will unconditionally evaluate both arguments and then unconditionally yield the left one, or unconditionally yield the right one.  The comma-operator syntax used in C may not be optimal for this, however.  There are at least three variations on such constructs for which I can see some real uses:

1. Perform the left, then perform the right, then yield the value of the right operand.
2. Perform both operations in either order, and then yield the right operand (if the surrounding code needs it, which it wouldn't in most cases).
3. Perform the left, then perform the right, then yield the value that had been produced by the left operand.

I'm not sure what syntax I'd favor for those operations, but I see no reason for the language to have a nicer syntax for the first than for the others.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only time I've used the comma operator is in `for` statements:

```
for (x=1,y=2,z=3;  x<17;  ++x,y*=2,z/=2) { … }
```

This is at least semi-useful (having all the iteration adjustments together, inside the `for`).
But other uses seem to be more confusing than useful.

Comment: Some languages with C-style `for` loops specially allow the "initialiser" and "step" parts to be comma-separated lists of expressions, when the language itself doesn't have a comma operator for expressions in general. E.g. [Java does this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1).